# Rspec error when I run my rspec test of my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

I am developing a **Rails v2.3** application.

When I run the **rspec** test by execute command:

`rspec spec/controllers/my_controller_spec.rb`

I got the **error message** which is showing below:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@myapp/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:427:in `raise_if_rspec_1_is_loaded':  (RuntimeError)
********************************************************************************
  You are running rspec-2, but it seems as though rspec-1 has been loaded as
  well.  This is likely due to a statement like this somewhere in the specs:

      require 'spec'

  Please locate that statement, remove it, and try again.
********************************************************************************
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@myapp/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:420:in `load_spec_files'
```

**----update---**

Since it complains about some file which contain the code `require 'spec'`, so I follow this clue and I found "`require 'spec'`" in **spec/spec_helper.rb** , **However**, after I **removed** it , the **same error still raise up**, and I don't have any other file contain the code now.

Why the error still coming, what is the real cause then?

Comment: how are the config/test.rb and the spec_helper files looking?

Comment: @ Alok, I found  "require 'spec'" in confi/test.rb , after I remove it , the same error still raise up, and I don't have any other file contain the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rspec` is the executable for `rspec-2`. `spec` is the executable for `rspec-1`. `rspec-2` is not compatible with `rails 2.3`. Your command should be:

```
spec spec/controllers/my_controller_spec.rb
```