# Rspec showing wrong version number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm running a Rails 2.3.4 app under ruby 1.8.7 and rvm with a custom gemset.

In trying to get rspec up and running, I've tried several times to uninstall rspec 2 and install rspec and rspec-rails version 1.3.4. However, when I run `rspec -v` I get 2.10.0 regardless of what I do.

Finally I got this error message:

```
You are running rspec-2, but it seems as though rspec-1 has been loaded as
  well.  This is likely due to a statement like this somewhere in the specs:

      require 'spec'

  Please locate that statement, remove it, and try again.
```

So it looks like 2.10.0 is actually still loaded. Even if I do a `gem uninstall rspec` rspec is still loaded. What's going on?

Comment: how about "bundle exec rspec -v" ?

Comment: I'm not running bundler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `spec` (the RSpec 1 executable) instead of `rspec`, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821020/rspec-error-when-i-run-my-rspec-test-of-my-controller).